# How to login in Google account via selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I tried to login via selenium to google account and get stuck

I know that we need to put some settings todo it

I tried:
[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzXCP.png)
But it doesn't help me

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a very bad approach and you shouldn't be automating them. It's not recommended to use WebDriver to log into these types of sites. It's against the usage terms, and it's slow and unreliable.**

Still if you want to do, please find the below reference Link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-automate-gmail-login-process-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java

https://www.edureka.co/community/2137/automate-gmail-login-process-using-selenium-webdriver-java

**Better Approach:**

> **The best approach is to use the JAVA Mailer API or GMAIL API.**
> The best to use the APIs that email providers offer or, in the case of Facebook, the developer tools service that exposes an API for creating test accounts. (The Gmail API is here.)

**Ref:**

**JAVA Mailer API:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm

**Gmail API:**

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

**In the Google Account Help page they say:**

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en